# Help with non-profit network

Tags: network

Our church network and 10 security camera system is is run by a i5 2500K - 8 GB memory with an AMD 5570 HD graphic to one monitor and the onboard Intel HD 3000 chip to a second monitor.

The current router is a Cradlepoint MBR 95 (10/100 ports) which I think I should replace.

We are having some glitches such as wifi dropouts and disconnects.  The Cradlepoint MBR 95 serves as our primary wifi while a Unifi Ubiquity the second.

I used multiple Switches because the church is old and hard to pull Cat5 cable.

1st question: Am I underpowered?

2nd question: Should I upgrade to better graphics and better router.

3rd question:  Can I chain a 4th Switch .. (Yellow line) or is that asking for trouble?  Here is the network diagram.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "underpowered"? Are you talking about PoE needs, throughput, wireless coverage, or something else? The host configuration (i.e. graphics) portions of the question are off topic here and should probably be removed.

Comment: Whatever router you chose, make sure it is designed to provide the services you need for the number of devices on your network. For example, many lower end devices start to fail when you have too many DHCP clients, concurrent connections, etc. Looking a the number of devices, you should be considering at least small business devices (and maybe even better classes of those devices).

Comment: Thanks guys ... I appreciate.  All Switches a Gigabit, yes, but the router ports are 10/100 that go out to the Switches.  I think underpowered in terms of graphics and the router .. the router has been at "end of life" about 4 years ago and the graphics card is pretty weak.  Thanks for clarifying about posting mfg products.  I will edit out.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> We are having some glitches such as wifi dropouts and disconnects.

WiFi dropouts and disconnects are an exclusive WiFi problem. There may be interference from outside or high attenuation due to distance or walls in between.

> Am I underpowered?

Do all links use Gigabit Ethernet right now? If not, at least the switches with more than just cameras on them should have GbE uplinks.

We can't tell whether there's enough bandwidth. With managed devices, you can check their consoles for signs of link oversubscription. With unmanaged devices, that is much harder to tell - you'd need to model the workloads.

> Should I upgrade to better graphics and better router?

Graphics looks OK to me but host configurations are off-topic here, sorry. If Internet connectivity is a problem (speed drops, frequent crashes at load peaks) you might need a better router - however, product recommendations are off-topic here as well.

> Can I chain a 4th Switch .. (Yellow line) or is that asking for trouble?

Chaining should generally be avoided as it can create bottlenecks and make problems harder to diagnose. Also, you should consider getting a managed central switch for easier troubleshooting.

But yes, chaining another switch is generally possible. Actually, there's no limit to chaining switches other than their MAC table capacity (and practical reasons - better switches using a form of spanning-tree protocol with default parameters may also fail to converge due to timeouts (thx @YLearn)).

Comment: Disagree with the "no limit to chaining switches" statement. Without RSTP running properly (still not default on many lower cost devices and fall back to STP is more likely with interoperability issues when using multiple vendors), STP typically fails with default timers when you exceed a seven switch diameter. While the current scenario only has a diameter of four, saying there is no limit could mislead the OP (or others) into thinking it is safe to exceed seven switches.

Comment: You're correct, but pretty obviously the OP is not running any form of STP. I also consider STP limits a "practical reason".

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I do want to point out that some TRENDnet switches support STP, not sure about BV-Tech. Without knowing model numbers, I personally wouldn't go out on a limb to say they are not running STP. One also can't say how the network (devices, topology) in question may change over the next 1/5/X years or the details of the network of someone else searching and finding this post.

Comment: Absolutely - thx for pointing to STP as the question may indeed be checked by others in another situation.

Answer (score 1):

Product recommendations are off topic here as well as consumer-grade devices such as the ones you have/want to buy.

That said, before you upgrade your hardware, understand why.  For example, you say you're having WiFi drops, but there can be many reasons (interference, poor placement, etc), and a new WiFI router may not fix them.

Generally, daisy-chaining switches is a bad idea, but if you can't help it...
Try not to oversubscribe the ports connecting the switches (remember you're aggregating traffic).

Comment: Instead of chaining a 4th Switch or running an additional Cat 5e cable would using a Cat 5 Splitter work as efficiently?  I have an extra port on the 4 port POE Switch so I might use a Cat 5 Splitter from it and branch back out at the other end.  At the termination end would be a IP Camera and a laptop.  That way I would only be chaining 3 Switches and use a single Network cable.  A second question is about "Uplink".  I have read where it makes no difference how it's plugged in ... but if that's so, why is it different?  I would think you would uplink downstream to the next Switch ...

Comment: @Griz Note that cable splitters are generally non-compliant and NESE is about business networks, usually requiring high reliability/conformity. Also a splitter limits you permanently to 100 Mbit/s and may cause problems with GbE ports on both sides (negotiating Gb and then being unable to link). Reluctantly, I'd rather chain another switch. "Uplink" and "downlink" are either about hierarchy (towards or away from the core) or port pinout: switch-to-switch and host-to-host connections used to require crossovers before Auto MDI-X.

Comment: Cable splitters are always a bad idea. As far as chaining goes: all the traffic on the switch goes through the uplink port.  So al the traffic gets aggregated to one port.  By the time you get to the most upstream switch, you have concentrated all the traffic from all the downstream switches.  There is the danger that you will exceed the bandwidth of that port.  But if you have only two devices on the most downstream switch, then it's probably not a problem.

Comment: Oh wow ... thanks guys.  That is all really helpful information.  Especially about the Auto MDI-X.  (Googled it) I learn something every day.  So if I understand it correctly (in the olden days) , if the 1st sending Switch has an Uplink port listed, then that is cabled to one of the common ports on the next Switch in line downstream, and if that Switch has an Uplink port show, just repeat the process.  Or is that irrelevant in today's technology?  Lastly .. Since my final Switch (4th) will have only 2 devices (laptop and camera) I might be ok then with the 4th Switch?.

Comment: Often, uplink ports are higher speed, but other than that,there is little difference.  Two devices on the switch should be OK.

Comment: Great, I appreciate the help and explanation.  And I understand now about aggregating the data to the one port on the 1st Switch.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Consider accepting my answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Wow .... I'm going to need a Notebook.  Thanks so much.  I'm looking as to where to accept your answer ... this is my 1st post so I'm finding my way around here.